# JAXB. Example of working code identical to broken code. (src in github link)

Tags: java, jaxb

https://github.com/akgithubtest/WhyIsItBroken

I cannot understand why one instance of JAXB usage is throwing the error `class Common.Broken nor any of its super class is known to this context.` and why another works perfectly fine. I've broken each down to a visual diff, and cannot even distinguish the difference. What am I missing here?

in Main.java, I have. It's a simple http server listening on two routes: `working` and `broken`. `broken` doesn't work. `working` does.

```
import Common.Broken;
import Common.Working;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8888;
        HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        httpServer.createContext("/broken", new BrokenHandler());
        httpServer.createContext("/working", new WorkingHandler());
        httpServer.setExecutor(null);
        httpServer.start();
    }

    static class BrokenHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange)
                throws IOException
        {
            try {
                Broken broken = new Broken();
                broken.age = 100;
                broken.id = 3;
                broken.name = "This doesn't work. Why?";

                ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(broken);
                responseHandler.RespondBroken(httpExchange);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    static class WorkingHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange)
                throws IOException
        {
            try {

                Working working = new Working();
                working.age = 100;
                working.id = 3;
                working.name = "This works";

                ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(working);
                responseHandler.RespondWorking(httpExchange);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `Common/Broken.java` I have the following (which is identical to `Common/Working.java`, but the name of the class and the file are called `Broken`.

```
package Common;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement (name = "broken")
public class Broken {

    @XmlElement public String name;
    @XmlElement public int age;
    @XmlAttribute public int id;

}
```

Just for the sake of it (in case there's anything I've missed, here's `Common/Working.java`:

```
package Common;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement (name = "working")
public class Working {

    @XmlElement public String name;
    @XmlElement public int age;
    @XmlAttribute public int id;

}
```

Finally, I have a response handler. The two functions are almost identical.

```
import Common.Working;
import Common.Broken;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ResponseHandler {

    public Broken broken;
    public Working working;

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Marshaller marshaller;


    public ResponseHandler(Working working)
            throws JAXBException
    {
        this.working = working;
        this.Init();
    }

    public ResponseHandler(Broken broken)
            throws JAXBException
    {
        this.broken = broken;
        this.Init();
    }


    private void Init()
        throws JAXBException {
        this.jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Working.class);
        this.marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    public void RespondWorking(HttpExchange httpExchange)
            throws JAXBException, IOException
    {
        java.io.StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        this.marshaller.marshal(this.working, output);
        String response = output.toString();
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void RespondBroken(HttpExchange httpExchange)
            throws JAXBException, IOException
    {
        java.io.StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
        this.marshaller.marshal(this.broken, output);
        String response = output.toString();
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
        OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I can't spot what I'm missing here. Am I going crazy?
(src in the github link).

Comment: Where's this error located?

Comment: Either STDOUT or STDERROR when you go the the url `http://localhost:8888/broken`. When I build in IntelliJ, it's in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that you're calling the `Init()` method for both the constructor which takes `Working` and the constructor which takes `Broken`.

Inside the `Init()` method you call `JAXBContext.newInstance(Working.class);`. When the `Init()` method is called through the constructor with `Broken` is called should be `JAXBContext.newInstance(Broken.class);` which it's not, and that's why it's throwing that error.